# Como faço para verificar quais itens da Lista2 estão na Lista1, em seguida sua contagem e ordem

Tags: python, lista, for

Sou iniciante no Python e gostaria de contar com o ajuda de vocês para os problemas abaixo.
Tenho trabalhado em duas listas como os seguintes objetivos:
1.Verificar quais itens da Lista2 estão na lista1
2.Fazer a contagem de cada item da Lista2 na Lista1 e ordená-los na Lista_ordenada.

```
Lista1 = ['a', 'k', 'j', 'd', 'p', 'u', 'j', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'c', 'p', 'e', 'u', 'z', 'z', 'f', 's', 'u', 'k', 'p', 'u', 'j', 'h', 'b', 'k', 'j', 'd', 'e', 'u', 'j', 'z']

Lista2 = ['j', 'u', 'z', 'k', 'u', 'p']

Lista_ordenada = [ ]


for i in  Lista1:
  if i == 'j' :
    break
Lista_ordenada.append('j')
.
.
.
for i in  Lista1:
  if i == 'p' :
    break
Lista_ordenada.append('p')
```

**Dos problemas:**

1. Embora o código funcione, vejo que está muito repetitivo e apresenta lentidão;
2. Embora tenha conseguido coloca-los na Lista_ordenada (de forma desordenada), não conseguir fazer a contagem, tão pouco ordena-los.

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Answer (score 0):

A abordagem que usou não é a mais eficiente pois para cada elemento de `Lista2` você teve que escrever um código específico para realizar a comparação e adição do elemento a `Lista_ordenada`, caso `Lista2` seja modificada seu código deixaria de cumprir o seu propósito e teria que ser escrito um novo laço de comparação para os novos elemento. Outra coisa nítida é questão da performance a verificação `Lista1` é reiterada tornando o algoritmo ineficiente.

Reanalisado a questão, são três os seus problemas:

1. Verificar quais itens da `Lista2` estão na `Lista1`.
2. Fazer a contagem de cada item da `Lista2` na `Lista1`.
3. Ordenar os itens na `Lista_ordenada`.

Para verificar quais itens da `Lista2` estão na `Lista1` tranforme-as em [conjuntos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) e faça a [intercessão](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) com o operador `&`.

Para fazer fazer a contagem de cada item da `Lista2` na `Lista1` crie [contadores](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) e use apenas os elementos que estejam em `Lista_ordenada` para filtrar o resultado(pois seus elementos são comuns as duas listas).

Para ordenar os itens na `Lista_ordenada` use a função embutida [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
from collections import Counter

Lista1 = ['a', 'k', 'j', 'd', 'p', 'u', 'j', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'c', 'p', 'e', 'u', 'z', 'z', 'f', 's', 'u', 'k', 'p', 'u', 'j', 'h', 'b', 'k', 'j', 'd', 'e', 'u', 'j', 'z']
Lista2 = ['j', 'u', 'z', 'k', 'u', 'p']

#Faz a intercessão de Lista1 e Lista2 e ordena o resultado.
Lista_ordenada = sorted(set(Lista1) & set(Lista2))

#Conta a frequencia de cada elemento de Lista1 e Lista2.
Contagem1 = Counter(Lista1)
Contagem2 = Counter(Lista2)

print(f"Elementos comuns as duas listas {Lista_ordenada}")

for k in Lista_ordenada:
  print(f"O elemento '{k}' aparece {Contagem1[k]} vez{'es' if Contagem1[k]>1 else '' } na lista1.")
  print(f"O elemento '{k}' aparece {Contagem2[k]} vez{'es' if Contagem2[k]>1 else '' } na lista2.")
  print(f"Num total de {Contagem1[k] + Contagem2[k]} aparições.")

#Elementos comuns as duas listas ['j', 'k', 'p', 'u', 'z']
#O elemento 'j' aparece 5 vezes na lista1.
#O elemento 'j' aparece 1 vez na lista2.
#Num total de 6 aparições
#O elemento 'k' aparece 5 vezes na lista1.
#O elemento 'k' aparece 1 vez na lista2.
#Num total de 6 aparições
#O elemento 'p' aparece 3 vezes na lista1.
#O elemento 'p' aparece 1 vez na lista2.
#Num total de 4 aparições
#O elemento 'u' aparece 5 vezes na lista1.
#O elemento 'u' aparece 2 vezes na lista2.
#Num total de 7 aparições
#O elemento 'z' aparece 3 vezes na lista1.
#O elemento 'z' aparece 1 vez na lista2.
#Num total de 4 aparições
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/TgdOuT)</sup>

Comment: Parece interessante sua exposição, mas não é exatamente isso. Correção: Na lista2  tem somente um 'u'.  No segundo problema, solicito que seja visto a contagem (ocorrências dos elementos)   da Lista2 na Lista1. Ex:  'j'  ocorre 5 vezes na Lista1. Então 'j' deve ser inserido em uma nova Lista de forma ordenada do > para o <, por ex: Lista_ordenada = ['j', 'k'......]  Se a solução vier em forma de função melhor, pois caso a Lista2 tenha menos elementos,  esses serão exposto em uma nova ordem.

Comment: @OberdanSantos Olhe sua pergunta está escrito `Lista2 = ['j', 'u', 'z', 'k', 'u', 'p']` na sua pergunta o elemento `u` se repete duas vezes,

Comment: @OberdanSantos, na pergunta está escrito *Fazer a contagem de cada item da Lista2 na Lista1 e ordená-los na Lista_ordenada.* não fala em momento algum que é para ordenar com base na sua frequencia.

Comment: @OberdanSantos Eu posso apena responder o que foi perguntado, não posso adivinhar suas intenções e objetivos se não os expressa.

Comment: Peço desculpas por não ter me expressado corretamente. Sei que precisamos de uma logica do problema para a solução do mesmo. Acredito q agora tenha ficado claro e que vc posse me ajudar.

Comment: @OberdanSantos Não meu tempo é caro e isso é pro bono. Eu respondi ao que estava escrito se não escreveu corretamente abra outra pergunta para que outra pessoa o responda.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a solução abaixo atenda sua necessidade:

**Input:**

```
lista1 = ['a', 'k', 'j', 'd', 'p', 'u', 'j', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'c', 'p', 'e', 'u', 'z', 'z', 'f', 's', 'u', 'k', 'p', 'u', 'j', 'h', 'b', 'k', 'j', 'd', 'e', 'u', 'j', 'z']
lista2 = ['j', 'u', 'z', 'k', 'u', 'p']
lista_ordenada = []

for i in  lista2:
  if i in lista1:
    item_tuple = (i, lista1.count(i))
    lista_ordenada.append(item_tuple)
 
lista_ordenada = sorted(lista_ordenada, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse = True)
print(lista_ordenada)
```

**Output:**

```
[('j', 5), ('u', 5), ('k', 5), ('u', 5), ('z', 3), ('p', 3)]
```

O loop do For checa se cada item da Lista2 está na Lista1 e, caso positivo, cria um tuple (item_tuple) do próprio item (i) com o número de ocorrências (lista1.count(i)).

Após criar o tuple, ele adiciona este conjunto na lista_ordenada através do método .append(item_tuple).

Por fim, a função sorted() ordena a lista_ordenada pelo segundo item do tuple, que é o número de ocorrências. Reverse = True foi utilizado para ordenar de maneira decrescente, visto que o padrão da função é a ordenação crescente.